# Return Full image Url in Django Rest Framework For Image

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am facing problem in returned image url, which is not proper.

My return image URL is
`"/media/slider_image/image/slider_image_4ea48daf-477d-4f00-93cb-7ac87c6f4002.JPG",`[image]

but actual URL expected from serializer is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/slider_image/image/slider_image_4ea48daf-477d-4f00-93cb-7ac87c6f4002.JPG
```

Here is my snippet of my Code that I have tried.

```
class ListSliderSerializer(SliderSerializers):
    images = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_images')

    def get_images(self, instance):
        return [slider_image.image.url for slider_image in instance.slider_image.all()]


    class Meta(SliderSerializers.Meta):
        fields = (
            'images',
            'section',
            'tag',
        )
```

what should i return in

```
return [slider_image.image.url for slider_image in instance.slider_image.all()]
```

to get full url for my image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**`request.build_absolute_uri(...)`**--(doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) method as

```
class ListSliderSerializer(SliderSerializers):
    images = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_images')

    def get_images(self, instance):
        request = self.context["request"]
        return [
            request.build_absolute_uri(slider_image.image.url)
            for slider_image in instance.slider_image.all()
        ]

    class Meta(SliderSerializers.Meta):
        fields = (
            'images',
            'section',
            'tag',
        )
```

Also note that you ***must*** pass `request` to the serializer as *context data*